# Excel VBA Search multiple worksheets & paste selected rows to summary worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently trying to scan columns D & K in multiple worksheets (the number may vary). If the value in column D is 9 or 10 or if the value in column K is >100 I want to copy the entire row to a summary sheet. It creates the summary worksheet but it doesn't copy any rows over. Here is what I have so far:

```
 Option Explicit

Sub AppendDataAfterLastColumn()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim DestSh As Worksheet
Dim Last As Long
Dim CopyRng As Range
Dim SearchRng As Range
Dim SearchRng1 As Range
Dim rngCell As Range
Dim lastrow As String

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

' Delete the summary worksheet if it exists.
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
On Error Resume Next
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Action Items").Delete
On Error GoTo 0
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

' Add a worksheet with the name "Action Items"
Set DestSh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
DestSh.Name = "Action Items"
Sheets("Action Items").Move Before:=Sheets(3)

Sheets(4).Select
Range("A1:U3").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Action Items").Select
Range("A1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("a1") = "PFMEA Action Items"

' Loop through all worksheets and copy the data to the
' summary worksheet.
For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

        If sh.Name <> DestSh.Name Then

            Set SearchRng = ActiveSheet.Range("D:D, K:K")

            ' Find the last row with data on the summary
            ' worksheet.
            Last = Worksheets("Action Items").UsedRange.Rows.Count

                For Each rngCell In SearchRng.Cells

                    If rngCell.Value <> "" Then

                        If rngCell.Value = "9" Or "10" Then
                        'select the entire row
                            rngCell.EntireRow.Select
                            MsgBox Selection.Address(False, False)
                            Selection.Copy

                            ' This statement copies values, formats, and the column width.

                            lastrow = DestSh.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
                            DestSh.Cells(lastrow, "A").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths, Operation:=xlNone, _
                                SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

                        ElseIf rngCell.Value > 100 Then

                            'select the entire row
                            rngCell.EntireRow.Select
                            Selection.Copy

                            ' This statement copies values, formats, and the column width.
                            lastrow = DestSh.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
                            DestSh.Cells(lastrow, "A").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths, Operation:=xlNone, _
                                SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

                        End If

                    End If

                Next rngCell

        End If
Next

ExitTheSub:

Application.Goto DestSh.Cells(1)

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
End With
End Sub
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: One problem I notice is that in your if statement `If rngCell.Value = "9" Or "10" Then` you do not have the second criteria. Replace with `If rngCell.Value = "9" Or rngCell.Value = "10" Then`. Also, it is good practice to avoid using select statements when possible. Just run the methods directly on the objects. :)

Comment: Thanks for the input. I made the change but didn't seem to change anything. I think my problem is something to do with how I'm selecting, copying, and then pasting.

Answer (score 1):

Add `sh.Activate` after  `If sh.Name <> DestSh.Name Then`

Also consider the comment given by 'PartyHatPanda'

Comment: Thanks for the input. I made the change but it seems to copy the wrong things and then gives an error with the paste method (pastespecial method of range class failed)

Comment: May be i understood your question wrong in that case. What i under stood is, you are trying to check the value of sheet1-D cells or K cells for some condition, if condition is met you cant to copy entire row where condition is met, and then copy it to `Action Items` and it does correctly when i tried your code just by doing the changes i suggested.

Comment: You understood correctly.I tried it on plain data and it worked, like you said. I think my problem is the data is withing a table and some of the cells are merged (vertically) and I get this message "There's already data here. Do you want to replace it?". Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is in your paste special code, you are telling it to paste column widths. I copied your code `DestSh.Cells(lastrow, "A").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False` and then I changed it to `DestSh.Cells(lastrow, "A").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False`. For me, it copies rows and values over. The way you wrote it, you may get duplicates depending on if the values in both columns d and in columns k fit the criteria. If this is not desired, you may want to either cut rows over or set up more criteria to work with. See if this helps any! :)

Comment: Thanks! This seemed to help a little.